# Can't purge messages from channel, discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I need to purge 10 messages as default and clear all channel, if printed `-чисти все`. It worked, but my bot now don't purge any message and I don't know what I can do for fix it. Help pls

````
    cha=ctx.message.channel
    author=ctx.message.author
    if all=='все' or all=="всё":

        amount=0
        history=await cha.history(limit=9999999).flatten()
        for i in history:
            amount+=1
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1000) # amount instead 1000```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount=10): # the amount is 10 
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount) # set the default clear limit to 10
```

Comment: I noticed my bot deleting messages, but do it sooooo slow) But it do this, so I don't have queres) Ty for feedback)

Answer (score 0):

If you're purging 10 messages, [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) has everything you need to purge the channel. You can get the channel using [`Context.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context%20channel#discord.ext.commands.Context.channel) and use the [`purge()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=textchannel%20p#discord.TextChannel.purge) method to purge messages in a TextChannel. Then you can use the `limit` kwarg to set a limit.

If you're trying to nuke the entire channel, [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) also allows you to easily get the channel to nuke by using [`Context.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context%20channel#discord.ext.commands.Context.channel). Get the position of the TextChannel to be deleted using the attribute [`position`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=textchannel%20p#discord.TextChannel.position), make a clone using the [`clone()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=textchannel%20clone#discord.TextChannel.clone) method of TextChannel and delete the original channel using [`delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=textchannel%20de#discord.TextChannel.delete). Then use [`TextChannel.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=textchannel%20ed#discord.TextChannel.edit) with the `position` kwarg to fix the channel list.